# for loop is only printing last iteration

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C program that takes a string input from a user and then looks into the input to count the frequency of all the integers in the string. So suppose if the user gives the input:

```
a11472o5t6
```

the output would be :

```
0 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

my approach involves comparing every character of the string to all 10 digits one by one and if any the character is equal to the digit, it would increment the **is<sub>digit</sub>** number by 1.
the code I wrote for the same is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is1 = 0; //initialise integers for checking
int is2 = 0;
int is3 = 0;
int is4 = 0;
int is5 = 0;
int is6 = 0;
int is7 = 0;
int is8 = 0;
int is9 = 0;
int is0 = 0;

int main()
{
    char s[100];        //initialise array for string
    scanf("%s", s);      //scan string input

    //now all characters of the string are stored in the array s
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)   //loop to iterate over all the elements in the array
    {
        if (strcmp(&s[i], "0") == 0)
        {
            is0 = is0 + 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(&s[i], "1") == 0)
        {
            is1 = is1 + 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(&s[i], "2") == 0)
        {
            is2 = is2 + 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(&s[i], "3") == 0)
        {
            is3 = is3 + 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(&s[i], "4") == 0)
        {
            is4 = is4 + 1;
            //printf("%d", is4);
        }
        if (strcmp(&s[i], "5") == 0)
        {
            is5 = is5 + 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(&s[i], "6") == 0)
        {
            is6 = is6 + 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(&s[i], "7") == 0)
        {
            is7 = is7 + 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(&s[i], "8") == 0)
        {
            is8 = is8 + 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(&s[i], "9") == 0)
        {
            is9 = is9 + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%d ", is0);
    printf("%d ", is1);
    printf("%d ", is2);
    printf("%d ", is3);
    printf("%d ", is4);
    printf("%d ", is5);
    printf("%d ", is6);
    printf("%d ", is7);
    printf("%d ", is8);
    printf("%d ", is9);
}
```

I expected the code to iterate over and over for the entire length of the string and and update values of the **is<sub>digit</sub>** series every time a number was successfully found. However whenever I run the code only the last digit seems to find its place in the output .
for example if I type `54` as an input the expected output is

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

however the output my code seems to be giving is

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

likewise the number `45` also has the same expected output

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

but the output I am receiving is

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

which looks like the code overwrites any operation that occurred in the previous iteration, but I can't seem to understand why and how to fix it.

On my part I checked if the characters were being called properly one by one and that all characters were being compared, where I found no problem. I also looked up other answers on stack overflow and elsewhere, but was I am a beginner and most answers were written in reference to languages that I can't understand, so I was unable to relate to the solution they were being told. the closest I got was someone who was using a single variable repetitively thus overwriting it in each iteration. however I have declared sufficient variables( one for each digit from 0-9), so that shouldn't be the problem in my code either.

while I know this question could be solved easily using arrays, I would like to know what I was doing wrong here to avoid any such mistakes in the future.

Comment: Every single one of those `strcmp(&s[i], "N") == 0` calls should be `s[i] == 'N'`. I don't think you understand how `strcmp` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `if (strcmp(&s[i],"1")==0)` you are comparing strings, not individual characters, which is why only the last character is counted. It's the only one matching.

Example:

If `s == "a11472o5t6"` and you use `strcmp(&s[1], "1")`, you would be comparing the string `"11472o5t6"` with the string `"1"`, which clearly will not be equal.

You want `if(s[i] == '1')` etc. to do the comparisons of individual characters instead.

And you are correct about using arrays instead. It'd certainly be easier.

Example:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char *str = "a11472o5t6";

    int ints[10] = {0};

    for (const char *chptr = str; *chptr != '\0'; ++chptr) {
        if(isdigit((unsigned char) *chptr)) ++ints[*chptr - '0'];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) printf("%d %d\n", i, ints[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
0 0
1 2
2 1
3 0
4 1
5 1
6 1
7 1
8 0
9 0
```